# Fundamental understanding of CSS Elements

Tags: css

```
     h1, p { position: absolute; left: -9999px; }

     div {position: relative;}

 #wrapper { background: #bedfe4 url(../images/sun.png) no-repeat left -30px; border: 5px    solid #402309;}

 #cloud-01 { background: url(../images/clouds-01.png) no-repeat left -100px; }                                                         

#cloud-02 { background: url(../images/clouds-02.png) no-repeat left top; }

#mountains-03 { background: url(../images/mountain-03.png) no-repeat left bottom; }

 #ground { background: url(../images/ground-05.png) no-repeat left bottom; }

#full-robot { width: 271px; }

 #branding {
background: url(../images/robot-head.png) no-repeat center top;
width: 271px;
height: 253px;
z-index: 4;
}

#content {
background: url(../images/robot-torso.png) no-repeat center top;
width: 271px;
height: 164px;
z-index: 3;
margin-top: -65px;
}

  #sec-content {
background: url(../images/robot-hips.png) no-repeat center top;
width: 271px;
height: 124px;
z-index: 2;
margin-top: -90px;
}

  #footer {
background: url('../images/robot-legs.png') no-repeat center top;
width: 271px;
height: 244px;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -90px;
}
```

1)Why h1 & p use absolute position versus div which using relative?

2)on h1's leftmargin  left:-9999px   Why need to make negative 9999 pixel to the left?is that offscreen?

3)In general those margin numbers are negative. rule of thumb downward and leftward are negative.   upward and rightward are positive?

Comment: 1. What makes this programming related? 2. You are posting a CSS file without the markup that comes with it and expect us to know why it was coded that way?

Comment: Could you rephrase those questions?

Comment: I don't know if I can avoid sounding mean here but this is really not the place for this kind of "question." You posted specific css for a specific page. This is not default boilerplate for anything so the only way to answer would be if you posted the html as well, but that would be a code audit and should be on another site specific to that need. SO is for debugging and help, not whatever this is.

Comment: understanding CSS is part of the programming skill. don't underestimate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is using absolute positioning with -9999px to move the elements off the screen. Why they chose to do this I don't know.

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow of the page. If you used relative you would have scrollbars that went very wide.

Negative top positioning draws the element upwards. Negative left positioning draws the element left. The opposite is true for positive numbers.